# NoMethodError: undefined method `errors' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I am building a web app and I got this error when running my test:

```
test "product attributes must not be empty" do
    product = Product.new
    assert product = product.invalid?
    assert product.errors[:title].any?
    assert product.errors[:description].any?
    assert product.errors[:price].any?
    assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
end
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `errors' for true:TrueClass
>       test/models/product_test.rb:7:in`block in '

Is it because I am using a newer version of Ruby than in the book? What would be the alternative if so?

Answer (score 7):

In line `assert product = product.invalid?` you assign result of `product.invalid?`, which is `true`, to `product` variable. It should be:

```
assert product.invalid?
```